# How do I treat the onclick parameter as a variable rather then a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am assigning a div to a variable;

```
function (MenuText) {
 var li = $("<div id='streamLinkOptions' onclick='editStreamDetails(" + MenuText + ")'><i class='fas fa- 
 caret-down'></i></div>");
}
```

I want the onclick function to execute with the provided parameter...

**MenuText is being treated as a string rather than a variable.**

My end goal is for MenuText to be passed into a function like the code below;

```
function editStreamDetails(title) {
    console.log(title);
}
```

---

Its possible that I am not using escapes properly. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: quote problems.

Comment: @FrV what do you mean?

Comment: `(\""+ MenuText +"\")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the event handler:

```js
function editStreamDetails(title) {
    console.log(title);
}
```

Then create the element:

```js
    $("<div id='streamLinkOptions'><i class='fas fa-caret-down'></i></div>");
```

Then attach the click handler to it!

Example:

```js
// define handler.
function editStreamDetails(title) {
    console.log(title);
}

function (MenuText) {
    // create element.
    var li = $("<div id='streamLinkOptions'><i class='fas fa-caret-down'></i></div>");

    // attach handler to event.
    li.find('.fa-caret-down').on('click', function() {
        editStreamDetails(MenuText);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! I want it so im clicking on the fas fa-caret-down rather then the li click

Comment: Answer updated to reflect your needs. Added a `.find()` to get the child element.

Comment: Hello!, I get undefined in my console.log

Comment: hmm. is your `var li` declaration this: `var li = $("<div id='streamLinkOptions'><i class='fas fa-caret-down'></i></div>");`. Make sure it is and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Register a click handler using jQuery to perform the appropriate action rather than try to do it all in one go.

```js
function(MenuText) {
  var li = $("<div id='streamLinkOptions'><i class='fas fa-caret-down'></i></div>");
  li.on('click', function() {
    editStreamDetails(MenuText)
  });
}
```

This will capture the value of `MenuText` and pass it to `editStreamDetails` when the `<div>` is clicked (assuming it gets added to the DOM at some point.)

**Update**

To register the click handler on the icon itself

```
li.find('i').on('click', function() {
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer, this seems really good. BUT, I want it so im clicking on the fas fa-caret-down rather then the li it self

Comment: Hello!, I get undefined in my console.log

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: So, I am building the li with $.each() function

Comment: This feels like a different issue/question.

Answer (score 0):

To add a click listener to an element with jQuery there is .click()

So you could get an existing element by its id with the selector $("#"+id_element) and add the click function on it with .click() like :

```
$("#streamLinkOptions").click(function(){//doSomething})
```

Comment: Hi, could you add more information about your answer ? Providing only code does not really helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to use the `onclick` attribute inline. Instead, you could add your data as an attribute and retreive this attribute in your click function. You should also register your click function using `addEventListener` instead.

```js
let titleOfDivs = [
  'test1',
  'test2'
]

titleOfDivs.forEach((title) => {
  $('body').append('<div class="streamLinkOptions" data-title="' + title + '"><i class="fas fa-caret-down></i></div>');
});

$('.streamLinkOptions').on('click', function() {
  let title = $(this).data('title');
  console.log(title);
})
```

```css
.streamLinkOptions {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

</body>
```

Here i've change your id to a class to make it easier to demonstrate.